# How to get Calendar field from REST request in RestController in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am getting date in POST request in `@RestController` with Json like this: 
`{ "date":"2016-01-28" }`
How can I get object with type `java.util.Calendar`?
Usually I use `java.util.Date`, but almost all methods are deprecated.
What Jackson annotation possible to use to get `Calendar`?
I tried to use

```
public class Test {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    Calendar date;
}
```

but get `null`

Comment: The new format to use is LocalDate -> take a look here [LocalDate](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-java-8-date-time-api-localdate-format.html)

Comment: What have you already tried? Please include your code to show us what you have attempted already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation `@DateTimeFormat`. According to Spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) it's applicable to `java.util.Calendar`.

```
@PostMapping("/somemapping")
public void date(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Calendar date) {
   //some other processing code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `java.util.Date` instead of a `Calendar`. At least in your repository object. If you need the additional functionality of a Calendar you can create an instance as demonstrated by `@Hamza`.

`Calendar` is a pretty heavy-weight class. No need to create a new instance of it considering the tiny amount of data you are storing.

You can pick out the date from another class that operates on it to provide you the additional functionality as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"calendar": 1558347802873  
}
```

Sample json request

just pass date in number format
use below object

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TestCal {

private Calendar calendar;

public Calendar getCalendar() {
    return calendar;
}

public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
    this.calendar = calendar;
}
}
```

sample spring Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/testCal")
    public void testCal(@RequestBody TestCal test) {

    // do your stuff
    test.getCalendar();


   }
```